How to add a new job to start at specific date(in the future) and run every day
Can anyone help me with this? New on rundeck here.
How to add a new job to start at specific date(in the future) and run every day?
e.g
Start the schedule in 2/2/2025 and everydate after this.
I cannot find how to say it to start in the specific date in the future.

The easiest way is to use the Calendars feature to blackout your daily job until 2/2/2025. Take a look at this. This feature is only available on Runbook Automation commercial products.
A "tricky" way: you need two jobs, the first one with your daily desired schedule but configured with disabled executions.
And another job with a script step enabling the execution and configured to run at the specific starting date (2/2/2025 in your case). You can configure this single execution on the jobs page, by clicking your job, clicking the "V" button list at the right of the "Run Job Now" green button, and selecting "Run Job Later", there you can put the 2/2/2025 date.
